# Remove picture compression for Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: ms-office

I'm trying to stop Word 2011 from compressing my pictures. In Windows, I can apparently do this by going to File > Options. However, there is no File > Options for Mac in Word 2011. Does anyone know how I can get Word to *stop* compressing my pictures?

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2011:

1. Double-click any image to bring up the `Format Picture` ribbon.
2. Click the `Compress` button, then choose `"Keep current resolution"` from the drop-down menu.
3. Choose to apply this setting to only the one image you double-clicked, or to all images in the file.